# Как создать линейный штрихкод на C# с выгрузкой в pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf, штрихкод

Такой вопрос возник. Существует некая веб-форма с выпадающими на ней списками, 3 списка всего, Необходимо при выборе значений по нажатию кнопки создать pdf-файл, на котором будут 3 числа и штрихкод, в котором закодированы эти числа.
Кодировка штрихкода должна быть такая [первое число][пробел][второе число][пробел][третье число]. Ранее с таким не сталкивался, поэтому прошу помощи.
Не понимаю как это реализовать. web-приложение

Comment: Штрихкоды обычно делаются просто выводом текста с barcode шрифтом, с символами `*` до и после. Найдите любой бесплатный barcode шрифт, и печатайте с ним текст в pdf - должно работать. https://ru.fonts2u.com/code-128.%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82, например

Comment: только учтите, что кодировки баркодов бывают разные, может быть вам нужен EAN13, а не EAN-128 - решается сменой шрифта

Comment: То есть, по сути, мне нужно создать строку, в нее передать эти числа используя шрифт для barcode и все?

Comment: @PashaPash а как при этом запихнуть получившуюся строку в пдф?

Comment: Для генерации PDF можете воспользоваться библиотекой iTextSharp или PDFsharp, лично мне больше нравится последний, особенно в связке с MigraDoc. Для ряда задач iText почти единственный вариант, но это не ваш случай, выбирайте что больше понравится.

Comment: @rdorn а существует возможность вывести в pdf файл без использования сторонней библиотеки?

Comment: Ну библиотеки как-то написали, посмотрите в их коде, но я бы так делать не стал, т.к. в итоге вам придется написать тоже самое. Вы какую версию PDF из, кажется, трех хотите? Для отображение на другой машине и печати шрифт придется интегрировать в PDF. Вам PDF или PDF-A? Вы хотите вывести в существующий PDF, ок, все те же вопросы + модификация структуры файла проприетарного формата с учетом всех его заморочек и необходимостью на выходе получить валидную структуру файла - готовы? Я нет.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое решение: я воспользовался выгрузкой через FastReport.

доп.класс для этого даже написал)

```
public static class FastReportExports
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Экспорт отчета FastReport в формат PDF
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fast_report"></param>
    public static void ToPdf(Report fast_report)
    {
        MemoryStream mem_str = new MemoryStream();
        fast_report.Export(new FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport(), mem_str);

    String report_name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fast_report.FileName) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", mem_str.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + report_name + ".pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(mem_str.GetBuffer());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();

    mem_str.Dispose();
}
}
```

Часть программного кода:

```
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        String Sklad = ddlZone.SelectedItem.Text;
        String Stack = ddlStack.SelectedItem.Text;
        String Pocket = ddlPocket.SelectedItem.Text;
        String tagText = ddlZone.SelectedItem.Text + " " + ddlStack.SelectedItem.Text + " " + ddlPocket.SelectedItem.Text;

        table.Columns.Add("ZONE_NAME");
        table.Columns.Add("STACK_NAME");
        table.Columns.Add("COUNT_OF_POCKETS");
        table.Columns.Add("BARCODE");
        TableRow rownew = new TableRow();
        table.Rows.Add(rownew);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            row["zone_name"] = Sklad;
            row["stack_name"] = Stack;
            row["count_of_pockets"] = Pocket;
            row["BARCODE"] = tagText;
        }



        //формирование отчета FastReport
        string ReportName = "Barcode.frx";
        string pp = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReportTemplates/FastReport/" + ReportName);

        WebReport WebRep = new WebReport();
        FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;
        WebRep.Report = new FastReport.Report();
        WebRep.Report.Load(pp);
        WebRep.Report.RegisterData(table, "Table");

        WebRep.Report.Prepare();
        FastReportExports.ToPdf(WebRep.Report);
        WebRep.Report.Dispose();
        WebRep.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib) довольно много информации по вашему вопросу.
Небольшой пример:

```
BarcodeLib.Barcode b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
Image img = b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.UPCA, "038000356216", Color.Black, Color.White, 290, 120); // получаем штрих-код типа Image
```

[image: Результат вышеуказанного кода]

Останется только генерировать PDF файл, советую посмотреть в сторону [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/index.html).
"Hello world" с SharpPDF:

```
pdfDocument myDoc = new pdfDocument("TUTORIAL","ME");
pdfPage myPage = myDoc.addPage();
myPage.addText("Hello World!",200,450,predefinedFont.csHelvetica,20);
myDoc.createPDF(@"c:\test.pdf");
myPage = null;
myDoc = null;
```

Comment: через FastReport это можно решить? потому что я использую его. Мне нужно как-то присвоить переменные с моего c# веб-приложения, в fastreport и уже с помощью fastreport файла создавать pdf для печати

Comment: @Sosiska, думаю да, хотя именно с FastReport не работал. У них есть объект типа [Barcode](https://www.fast-report.com/documentation/UserManFrNET-en/index.html?barcodeobject.htm), плюс [экспорт](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100788/export-a-pdf-using-fastreport-net-and-asp-net).